# Define checkboxes statuses before rendering new record form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `Tag` model `has_one :tag_option` with some checkboxes. When I'm creating new `Tag`, it gives a new `html form` in which all `tag_option` checkboxes are unchecked. I want to set some of them checked by default. What is the best way to do this?

Controller:

```
def new 
  @tag = Tag.new
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@tag) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :tag_option do |o| %>
    @tag.tag_option['status'] = true # It gives an error
    <%= o.check_box :status %>
    ....
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try with the following.

```
def new 
  @tag = Tag.new
  @tag_option = @tag.build_tag_option({status: true})
end
```

FORM

```
<%= form_for(@tag) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :tag_option do |o| %>
    <%= o.check_box :status %>
    ....
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```